# Comparing attributes from 2 sets

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have 2 sets of data, let's say, `Workers` and `Platform`. Both have attributes, say, `Drilling`, `Grinding`, `Hammering`.

I need a way to compare, in Excel, the attributes for each element within both sets. For example, if Platform A requires Hammering and Drilling, and Worker A has Drilling, Grinding and Hammering, he'd be accepted for platform A. Worker B only has Drilling, so he'd be rejected at platform B.

The following spreadsheet illustrates this clearly:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qvkZbDNIWe9gmFjGNr4dhtvqagJZOkS89YD4fzqjvQQ/edit?usp=sharing

In the sheet, "Canta Baila Pinta" are the attributes. The solution I've come up so far is: 
Generate a string for each `Worker` and `Platform`, which equals to its attributes

How do I compare both strings as if to ask, "Does string B contain any element not present in B?"

Furthermore, this code is not dynamic... how would you go about making it so that any newly added attribute got processed automatically, without user intervention?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output (and to avoid downvotes skip the excel tag lol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't dynamic, but here's another approach that may be of interest:

```
=ArrayFormula(mmult(if(Trabajadores!E2:G6="Sí",1,0),if(Plataformas!B2:F4="Sí",1,0))=
mmult(transpose(row(Plataformas!B2:F4))^0,if(Plataformas!B2:F4="Sí",1,0)))
```

[image]

The idea is that you multiply the Trabajadores and Plataformas matrices (converting Sí into 1, anything else to zero) to count the number of correspondences in skills for each worker/platform combination. Then you calculate the column totals of requirements in the plataformas matrix by doing another mmult, and finally compare the results to see which workers have the required number of skills for each platform.

Comment: I don't understand the entire formula, but the ^0 part is very elegant. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### delete all your formulae and use these:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(E2:E="Sí", E1, )&
 IF(F2:F="Sí", F1, )&
 IF(G2:G="Sí", G1, ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(IF(INDIRECT("B2:"&ROW()-1)<>"", 
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW()-1), ),,999^99), " ", ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 {Trabajadores!A:A, Trabajadores!H:H}, 2, 0)&" "&
 HLOOKUP(B1:F1, {Plataformas!B1:1; INDIRECT("Plataformas!B"&
 MATCH("Endstring", Plataformas!A:A, 0)&":"&
 MATCH("Endstring", Plataformas!A:A, 0))}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 {Trabajadores!A:A, Trabajadores!H:H}, 2, 0)&SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN(B1:F1)^0, 1, )), 
 SUBSTITUTE(ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A2:A)+1))^0, 1, )&
 HLOOKUP(B1:F1, {Plataformas!B1:1; INDIRECT("Plataformas!B"&
 MATCH("Endstring", Plataformas!A:A, 0)&":"&
 MATCH("Endstring", Plataformas!A:A, 0))}, 2, 0))))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JpSHaZJLLWtfQRVgHsa7l1tr02ZhEN0qmV1pvCeXcYw/edit#gid=1890193919)

Comment: Thank you infinitely. I had no idea that formulae such as QUERY, ROW & INDIRECT existed but I've always needed them.
There is still a final riddle I can't solve. We already have the attribute values for set A (workers) & set b (platforms). E.g. Alberto has "Canta" & "Baila" attributes. Platform 1 has "Canta".
How do I test the following:
Is there any attribute for value X in set B, that is not present in set A?

For example, Platform2 x Alberto should give "TRUE" to this question. Platform 2 has Pinta which Alberto doesn't have

Comment: Thank you very much for your help bro.

Comment: not sure I understood you... you mean like eliminating duplicates in cell like for example B2 contains 2x Canta so get rid of 2nd Canta?

Comment: yes! Sorry for the delay. what I mean is something like this:Imagine dividing each result in each cell. We have

Comment: yes! Sorry for the delay. what I mean is something like this:Imagine dividing each result in each cell. We have 'CantaBaila' for Alberto & 'Canta' for 'Plataforma 1' 
in cell B2.// If 'Alberto' wants to work in 'Plataforma 1', he must have at least all the skills in Plataforma 1.
The two "sets" are 'Plataforma' & 'Workers'. 
The values are "Baila", "Pinta", "Canta"
That's why I need a test to know, for any given cell, is there any element present in "Plataforma" that is not present in "Workers"?
Thanks, yesterday I was doing stuff.

Comment: I see. can you draft some example of what desired output should look like?

Comment: Sure! In the same link (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qvkZbDNIWe9gmFjGNr4dhtvqagJZOkS89YD4fzqjvQQ/edit#gid=435540969) there's a version of this calculation done manually. Only for Alberto & Dante. Alberto doesn't have "Pinta" but has the other 2. So only in the cross for Platform 2 & 4 he is TRUE
Dante only has one skill, and no platform has this skill only, so TRUE for all

Comment: @Baldomero answer updated. also demo sheet included